# On GKE, dcgm-exporter pod fails to run if the nvidia.com/gpu resource is not allocated

Tags: gpu, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubernetes-pod, nvidia-docker

I am trying to query GPU usage metrics of GKE pods.

Here is what I've done for test:

1. Created GKE cluster with two node pools, one of them has two cpu-only nodes and the other has one node with NVIDIA Tesla T4 GPU. All nodes are running Container-Optimized OS.
2. As written in https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers, I ran `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml`.
3. `kubectl create -f dcgm-exporter.yaml`

```
# dcgm-exporter.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: "dcgm-exporter"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
spec:
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
      name: "dcgm-exporter"
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator
                operator: Exists
      containers:
      - image: "nvidia/dcgm-exporter:2.0.13-2.1.1-ubuntu18.04"
        # resources:
        #   limits:
        #     nvidia.com/gpu: "1"
        env:
        - name: "DCGM_EXPORTER_LISTEN"
          value: ":9400"
        - name: "DCGM_EXPORTER_KUBERNETES"
          value: "true"
        name: "dcgm-exporter"
        ports:
        - name: "metrics"
          containerPort: 9400
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: false
          runAsUser: 0
          capabilities:
            add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "pod-gpu-resources"
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: "/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources"
      tolerations:
        - effect: "NoExecute"
          operator: "Exists"
        - effect: "NoSchedule"
          operator: "Exists"
      volumes:
      - name: "pod-gpu-resources"
        hostPath:
          path: "/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources"
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "dcgm-exporter"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '9400'
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
  ports:
  - name: "metrics"
    port: 9400
```

4. The pod runs only on the gpu node but crashes with the following error:

```
time="2020-11-21T04:27:21Z" level=info msg="Starting dcgm-exporter"
Error: Failed to initialize NVML
time="2020-11-21T04:27:21Z" level=fatal msg="Error starting nv-hostengine: DCGM initialization error"
```

With uncommenting the `resources: limits: nvidia.com/gpu: "1"`, it successfully runs. However, I don't want this pod to occupy any GPU but just watch them.

How can I run the dcgm-exporter without allocating GPU to it? I tried with Ubuntu nodes but failed, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked with these:

1. Set `privileged: true` to `securityContext`.
2. Add volume mount `"nvidia-install-dir-host"`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: "dcgm-exporter"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
spec:
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
      name: "dcgm-exporter"
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator
                operator: Exists
      containers:
      - image: "nvidia/dcgm-exporter:2.0.13-2.1.1-ubuntu18.04"
        env:
        - name: "DCGM_EXPORTER_LISTEN"
          value: ":9400"
        - name: "DCGM_EXPORTER_KUBERNETES"
          value: "true"
        name: "dcgm-exporter"
        ports:
        - name: "metrics"
          containerPort: 9400
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "pod-gpu-resources"
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: "/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources"
        - name: "nvidia-install-dir-host"
          mountPath: "/usr/local/nvidia"
      tolerations:
        - effect: "NoExecute"
          operator: "Exists"
        - effect: "NoSchedule"
          operator: "Exists"
      volumes:
      - name: "pod-gpu-resources"
        hostPath:
          path: "/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources"
      - name: "nvidia-install-dir-host"
        hostPath:
          path: "/home/kubernetes/bin/nvidia"
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "dcgm-exporter"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '9400'
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "dcgm-exporter"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.1.1"
  ports:
  - name: "metrics"
    port: 9400
```

Comment: Hey @yslee, could you provide me with a resource that lists all the configuration steps needed to install `dgcm-exporter` on GKE, please? Having some trouble following this [tutorial](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/monitoring-gpus-in-kubernetes-with-dcgm/)

Comment: @Jules Which step are you stuck on? I will try on this weekend.

Comment: When following the steps [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/kubernetes/dcgme2e.html#install-nvidia-device-plugin), after running: `helm install --generate-name nvdp/nvidia-device-plugin` the `nvidia-device-plugin` are stuck to `CrashLoopBackOff`...

Comment: However, I've installed the NVIDIA drivers as recommended by Google [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I installed dgcm-exporter by helm today and here is my values:

```
serviceMonitor:
  enabled: true

resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 100m
    # increase if OOM
    memory: 200Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi

securityContext:
  privileged: true

tolerations:
  - operator: Exists

affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator
              operator: Exists

# can ingore below
podAnnotations:
  ad.datadoghq.com/exporter.check_names: |
          ["openmetrics"]
  ad.datadoghq.com/exporter.init_configs: |
          [{}]
  ad.datadoghq.com/exporter.instances: |
    [
      {
        "openmetrics_endpoint": "http://%%host%%:9400/metrics",
        "namespace": "nvidia-dcgm-exporter",
        "metrics": [{"*":"*"}]
      }
    ]

extraHostVolumes:
  - name: vulkan-icd-mount
    hostPath: /home/kubernetes/bin/nvidia/vulkan/icd.d
  - name: nvidia-install-dir-host
    hostPath: /home/kubernetes/bin/nvidia

extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: nvidia-install-dir-host
    mountPath: /usr/local/nvidia
    readOnly: true
  - name: vulkan-icd-mount
    mountPath: /etc/vulkan/icd.d
    readOnly: true
```

I think no need to allocate gpu to dgcm, and record my step [here](https://locustbaby.github.io/2023/12/19/2023-12-19-gpu-on-gke/).